# is there any way to swap the function of two keys on keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, lenovo-laptop

My Lenovo Z500 laptop's <kbd>End</kbd> button is broken.
Is there any way to swap its function with <kbd>PgUp</kbd> button?
I know I can close <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> and use number <kbd>1</kbd> instead but I also need numbers.

[image: lenovo Z500 keyboard]
<sup>click to enlarge</sup>

Comment: Did you check the price of a new keyboard, generally, for  $20-$40 you can get a new one.  Then goto lenovo and get the installation instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, yes you can. You basically want to rebind a key on the key map.
To do this you have to fiddle around in the Windows Registry, [Map any key](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)
You can also simply use a tool, like this one:[SharpKeys](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)

I have no experience with Windows 10, so i used these links because they would have tested and verified it with Windows 10.

Comment: This answers the OP's real question, but not his precise title. SharpKeys can not swap as in A<->B and B<->A. I quote: "Things that SharpKeys will not do: Allow you to swap two keys with each other - e.g. you can’t have Q and Z swap places because the remapping code would get confused" from https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys (this function is what I need)

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, on Windows 11, you can install PowerToys and remap keys as you wish. This can be installed from the Store or Github. Here is an example of remapping a key

1. After installing, it will automatically open. Choose Keyboard manager as shown

[image]

2. In the keyboard manager part, remap your keys as desired

[image]